# Read only one line every time, with or without an "\n" at the end

Tags: python, file

I have a file which is filled like this:

```
Samsung CLP 680/ CLX6260 + CLT-C506S/ELS + CLT-M506S/ELS + CLT-Y506S/ELS + 39.50
Xerox Phaser 6000/6010/6015 + 106R01627 + 106R01628 + 106R01629 + 8.43
Xerox DocuPrint 6110/6110mfp + 106R01206 + 106R01204 + 106R01205 + 7.60
Xerox Phaser 6121/6121D + 106R01466 + 106R01467 + 106R01468 + 18.20
```

When I read it with:

```
for line in excelRead:
    title=line.split("+")
    title=[lines.strip()for lines in title]
```

sometimes there is an "\n" at the end of the line, and sometimes there is not, if line ends with \n splitting gives me 5 elements, if not 9 and etc., until it founds and "\n" as I guess

So, the question is: How do I read only one line in file each time, and obtain 5 elements every time, with or without an "\n" at the end? I can't check all all file whether there is, or not an "\n" at the end
Thanks

Comment: When \n is missing, is item 5 like '8.43Xerox DocuPrint 6110/6110mfp'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using the csv module to parse this, and placing into a dict by model:

```
import csv

data={}
with open('/tmp/excel.csv') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter='+', skipinitialspace=True):
        data[line[0].strip()]=[e.strip() for e in line[1:]]

print data        
# {'Samsung CLP 680/ CLX6260': ['CLT-C506S/ELS', 'CLT-M506S/ELS', 'CLT-Y506S/ELS', '39.50'], 
   'Xerox Phaser 6121/6121D': ['106R01466', '106R01467', '106R01468', '18.20'], 
   'Xerox DocuPrint 6110/6110mfp': ['106R01206', '106R01204', '106R01205', '7.60'], 
   'Xerox Phaser 6000/6010/6015': ['106R01627', '106R01628', '106R01629', '8.43']}
```

Comment: So, when I'm trying to do the way you said, it gives me 

  data[line[0].strip()]=[e.strip() for e in line[1:]]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]

Why?

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in excelRead:
    title = [x.strip() for x in line.rstrip('\n').split('+')]
```

It's better to avoid making one variable (`title`) mean two different things. Rather than give it a different name in your second line, I just removed the line entirely and put the `split` inside the list comprehension.

Instead of feeding `line` into `split`, first I [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) the `\n` (removes that character from the end)

Answer (score 0):

When \n is missing, this will split title[4] to give two titles:

```
import re
data = []
with open('aa.txt') as excelRead:
    for line in excelRead:
        title=line.split("+")
        title=[lines.strip()for lines in title]
        while len(title) > 5:
            one = re.sub('(\d+\.\d+)', '', title[4])
            five = title[4].replace(one, '')
            title1 = title[:4] + [five]
            title = [one] + title[5:]
            data.append(title1)
        data.append(title)
for item in data:
    print(item)
```

You could easily make data a dictionary instead of a list.